# Organizing and setting state from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have some data (objects) that live in their own file (Origin.js).

This data is being exported using the spread operator within another object named `OriginState`:

**Origin.js**

```
//info
const info = {
    title: '',
    year: '',
};

//images
const images = {
    logo: '',
    heroImage: '',
};

//text
const text = {
    header: '',
    body: '',
};

export const OriginState = {
    ...info,
    ...images,
    ...text,
};
```

I am importing my `OriginState` object in another file and using it as `state` for my app like this:

**OtherFile.js**

```
import { OriginState } from './Origin.js';

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        ...OriginState,
    });
```

Here is an example handler where I am using this state to update some specified state values in an input later:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        [name]: value,
    }));
};
```

Now, my question is... Is it incorrect to store `state` like this?

Additionally, am I using `setState` incorrectly in my handler function?

In most cases I've seen state declared and updated like this which is obviously easier to read:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
setCount(count + 1)
```

But I have a lot of `state` and didn't think it would be a good idea to have multiple `setState` hooks.

Is there a better way to do this? What I currently have just feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it incorrect to store state like this?
>
> ```
> const handleChange = (e) => {
>     const { name, value } = e.target;
>     setState((state) => ({
>         ...state,
>         [name]: value,
>     }));
> };
> ```

Nope, not at all, in fact, it is often the preferable pattern for state updates.

Any time your state update ***depends*** on the previous state, i.e. the classic counter example, or in your case, when there is nested state, you should use a functional state update to update from the previous state instead of the state from the previous render cycle.

> Additionally, am I using setState incorrectly in my handler function?
>
> In most cases I've seen state declared and updated like this which is
> obviously easier to read:
>
> ```
> const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
> setCount(count + 1)
> ```

I see no issue with your state update logic in the handler. In this `count` example it would (should) be considered incorrect to update a count like this. See this codesandbox demo that attempts to show the issue between non-functional and functional state updates.

[image: Edit react - regular and functional state updates]

The correct state update should be `setCount(count => count + 1)`

> But I have a lot of state and didn't think it would be a good idea to
> have multiple setState hooks.
>
> Is there a better way to do this? What I currently have just feels
> wrong.

When it comes to form inputs and state I think it makes sense to have a single flat object. There isn't really a right or wrong answer in general though when it comes to using a single `useState` hook with "complex" state shape, or to use a single `useState` hook for each "chunk" of state. It's an opinionated answer, mostly do what makes sense for a specific use-case.

Generally though I'd say if a set of values are even loosely related then perhaps it makes sense to store them in a common object, but this is *my* opinion.

A potential issue I see with your imported data though is the chance that you may inadvertently overwrite some key-value pairs by the use of the Spread syntax.

```
export const OriginState = {
    ...info,
    ...images, // <-- could overwrite values from info
    ...text, // <-- could overwrite values from info and images
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, I really appreciate the sandbox example since it does clear some things up for me. - I've seen others utilize the `useCallback` hook to prevent re-renders, do functional state updates work as an alternative? - Also, for the potential issue with spread, what's the fix? Should I export those objects individually?

Comment: `useCallback` solves a different issue. It simply memoizes a function so you can provide a stable callback reference to children components and the callback prop value won't change between renders unless one of the callback's dependencies updates. No, the spread is fine, just that you should be aware if you define duplicate keys then the later spread one will overwrite the first. If you also export each "chunk" then you have more options available later for how you may want to merge these objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems quite legit, and this is one of the best practices that if your `newState` is depend on the `oldState` use `setState callback` and get the old state from `callback input` because otherwise as you showed above if you use it like this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
setCount(count + 1)
```

you may increase the chance to get `stale data` which will increase the potential for bug

Comment: Thank you for the answer. - It's reaffirming to know that this is ok. That being said, I guess my issue is that I have multiple handler functions in my `OtherFile.js`. I'm sending these functions down to multiple components along with `state` coming from `Origin.js`. It just seems messy since some of these components have over 20 props. I fear there will be a point where this is not manageable.

Comment: `state` itself doesn't come from `Origin.js`, it's just the default value for `state` that are come from `Origin.js` file. and if you have multiple places that are using the same default state it's a good call to store them in a seperate file like `Origin.js` instead of copy-pasting it in all these places @AibCodesDaily

Comment: I appreciate your help! Thank you for confirming my doubts and adding to my knowledge. I started this app a while ago and forgot why I did some things the way I did. The confirmation will help me move forward.

Comment: @AibCodesDaily Glad I could help. Cheers